# Заливка слоя-маски

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, svg

**Предыстория**

Хочу написать некую "систему уровней".
Есть три переменные:

```
Score - Текущее количество очков;
ScoreNext - Количество очков до нового уровня;
Level - Текущий уровень;
```

Механику подсчёта опустим, приведу пример:
У пользователя 10 очков, он на 1 уровне, для следующего нужно набрать 20 очков.

```
1 LVL (0) | #####10%----- | 2 LVL (20) // Не не хватает 10 очков == 10%
```

Надеюсь понятно, переходим дальше.

**Идея**

Пользовались программой **Steam**? Если да, то понять меня будет проще.
Но всё же расскажу:

В Steam используются уровни и их много (на данный момент 4999).

[image: Steam Level]
Каждый уровень разбит на "группы"(вертикальные столбцы): Первые 100 - круг, вторые 100 - шестиугольник и т.д. (на скрине видно).
Так же каждая группа разбита ещё на группы (горизонтальные столбцы) - 0-10 - серый цвет изображения, 10-20 - красный и т.д..

**Что хочу**

Реализовать подобное на SVG.
При этом цвет будет заполнятся как прогресс-бар, снизу-вверх, в процентном соотношение.
Сама "иконка" уровня (вертикальные столбцы на скрине) - маска-слой изображение (SVG или растровое изображение).
При этом всё это будет изменяться через JS\JQ.

**Что нужно**
Как сверстать разметку самого SVG, что "крутить" чтобы JS\JQ кодом можно было управлять "уровнями" (картинкой, цветами, процентным соотношением).

---

P.s. Вопрос в основном для @Alexandr_TT, он попросил задать его в виде вопроса тут, но если кому-то интересна данная идея - прошу писать ответы или комментарии.

P.s. Слой-маска или Alpha texture.

[image: Слой-маска]

Ближе к чёрному - прозрачное.

---

"значок" уровня, пример:

```css
body {background: gray;}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="64px" width="64px" viewBox="-30 0 512 512">
<path d="m25.601562 162.132812c-4.714843 0-8.535156 3.820313-8.535156 8.535157v8.53125h-8.53125c-4.714844 0-8.535156 3.820312-8.535156 8.535156 0 4.710937 3.820312 8.53125 8.535156 8.53125h8.53125v8.535156c0 4.710938 3.820313 8.53125 8.535156 8.53125 4.710938 0 8.53125-3.820312 8.53125-8.53125v-8.535156h8.535157c4.710937 0 8.53125-3.820313 8.53125-8.53125 0-4.714844-3.820313-8.535156-8.53125-8.535156h-8.535157v-8.53125c0-4.714844-3.820312-8.535157-8.53125-8.535157zm0 0" fill="#FFFFFF"/><path d="m392.535156 17.066406h-8.535156v-8.53125c0-4.714844-3.820312-8.535156-8.535156-8.535156-4.710938 0-8.53125 3.820312-8.53125 8.535156v8.53125h-8.535156c-4.710938 0-8.53125 3.820313-8.53125 8.535156 0 4.710938 3.820312 8.53125 8.53125 8.53125h8.535156v8.535157c0 4.710937 3.820312 8.53125 8.53125 8.53125 4.714844 0 8.535156-3.820313 8.535156-8.53125v-8.535157h8.535156c4.710938 0 8.53125-3.820312 8.53125-8.53125 0-4.714843-3.820312-8.535156-8.53125-8.535156zm0 0" fill="#FFFFFF"/><path d="m443.734375 477.867188h-8.535156v-8.535157c0-4.710937-3.820313-8.53125-8.53125-8.53125-4.714844 0-8.535157 3.820313-8.535157 8.53125v8.535157h-8.53125c-4.714843 0-8.535156 3.820312-8.535156 8.53125 0 4.714843 3.820313 8.535156 8.535156 8.535156h8.53125v8.53125c0 4.714844 3.820313 8.535156 8.535157 8.535156 4.710937 0 8.53125-3.820312 8.53125-8.535156v-8.53125h8.535156c4.710937 0 8.53125-3.820313 8.53125-8.535156 0-4.710938-3.820313-8.53125-8.53125-8.53125zm0 0" fill="#FFFFFF"/><path d="m153.601562 443.734375c-39.085937 0-58.625-24.917969-65.453124-52.652344-7.707032 16.46875-11.589844 34.46875-11.347657 52.652344 0 49.75 91.902344 51.199219 102.398438 51.199219 63.148437 0 102.402343-39.253906 102.402343-102.398438 0-42.242187-28.84375-74.414062-47.875-91.050781 3.671876 29.863281 5.71875 83.539063-20.222656 115.796875-14.632812 17.832031-36.867187 27.648438-59.902344 26.453125zm0 0" fill="#FFFFFF"/><path d="m153.601562 221.867188c0 34.132812 17.066407 85.332031-25.601562 85.332031-17.066406 0-34.132812-17.066407-34.132812-42.664063 0-25.601562 25.597656-51.203125 25.597656-51.203125s-119.464844 25.601563-119.464844 179.203125c0 52.222656 24.917969 89.425782 97.707031 104.019532-21.164062-9.898438-37.972656-26.199219-37.972656-52.820313 0-54.101563 26.964844-81.664063 28.074219-82.859375 2.453125-2.421875 6.121094-3.128906 9.300781-1.792969 3.207031 1.285157 5.304687 4.398438 5.289063 7.851563 0 28.84375 13.484374 59.734375 51.203124 59.734375 17.847657 1.175781 35.175782-6.28125 46.589844-20.054688 31.488282-39.253906 13.570313-122.367187 13.3125-123.136719-.78125-3.375.554688-6.886718 3.378906-8.886718 2.828126-2.003906 6.582032-2.097656 9.507813-.242188 2.984375 1.875 72.277344 45.992188 72.277344 118.1875 0 48.980469-21.421875 86.269532-57.601563 105.214844 69.121094-13.058594 142.933594-52.738281 142.933594-156.417969 0-119.464843-119.464844-145.066406-119.464844-221.867187 0-82.6875 32-109.308594 34.046875-110.847656-4.4375 1.539062-144.980469 53.675781-144.980469 213.25zm0 0" fill="#FFFFFF"/></svg>
```

**UPD**

Вот что-то такое, косяков много

```js
$('select').bind('change', function(){
 let c = $(this).val();
  $('.lvl-icon').attr('class','lvl-icon '+c).find('animate').attr('dur', '5s');
});

$('input').bind('change mousemove', function(){
 let c = $(this).val();
  $('#change').attr('height', c+'%');
});
```

```css
.lvl-icon {
  fill: none;
  stroke: transparent;
  stroke-width: 10;
  mask: url(#mask);
}

.lvl-icon .none {display: none;}
.lvl-icon.gray {stroke: gray;}
.lvl-icon.red {stroke: red;}
.lvl-icon.cur #curcle,
.lvl-icon.quad #quad {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="cur gray" selected>lvl 00-10 - gray</option>
  <option value="cur red">lvl 10-20 - red</option>
  <option disabled>Ниже будет другая картинка</option>
  <option value="quad gray">lvl 20-30 - gray</option>
  <option value="quad red">lvl 30-40 - red</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="range" min="0" value="50" max="100" step="1">

<br><br>

<svg class="lvl-icon cur gray" height="200" width="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask" >
    <rect fill="white" width="100%" height="100%" />    
    <rect id="change" fill="red" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" >
   </rect> 
  </mask> 
  </defs>
  <circle id="curcle" class="none" cx="100" cy="100" r="90" />
  <rect id="quad" class="none" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" stroke-width="10" />
</svg>
```

Comment: steam это имеется в виду габеновский? не понятно о каких таких уровнях идет речь

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 иконки свои добавь, чтобы было всё конкретно

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, иконки ещё не придумал, "листочек" использовать можно?)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 да любое изображение, главное, чтобы **svg** было и габаритные размеры обязательно должны быть **одинаковые**.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, с SVG ещё не работал, могу только растровое скинуть, пойдёт?

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 нет, не пойдёт, растр не стилизуется обычным порядком, только через одно место.

Comment: Думаю, на такое сложное задание ответят только если начнешь конкурс.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, ахах, понял, спасибо что предупредили. Сейчас что-нибудь придумаю

Comment: Т.е. я правильно понял, на входе у нас процент и огромная картинка разбитая на более мелкие, а на выходе одна картинка + заполненная цветом до определенного уровня. Всего 5 уровней в игре. Так?

Comment: @MishaSaidov, нет, не совсем. SVG картинка будет одна (вместо 10 цветных, как в примере), дальше будет заливаться цветом в зависимости от уровню, каждый 100й лвл, допустим, будет отдельной SVG картинкой.

Comment: Т.е. таких замысловатых фигур не будет? Будет только одна?

Comment: @VerNick, будут, они будут после "просчёта" выводиться. Суть в том, что сами фигуры будут SVG и в виде маски)

Comment: Попробуйте убрать из вопроса лишнее. Для конкретной проблемы, тут слишком много не относящегося к ней контекста

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Сначала была лишь анимация заливки в стакан:

```css
#пуск {cursor: pointer;}
#жижа {stroke:#a50; 
       stroke-linecap: butt; 
       stroke-width:200%; 
       stroke-opacity:.6}
```

```html
<!-- SVG код -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg version = "1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:ev = "http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
     height = "200px"  width = "200px"
     viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="none"
     style ="border: 1px solid blue;">
<title>SVG анимация - линии</title>
  
  <defs>
    <path id="менза" fill="url(#жижа)" stroke="#daa" stroke-width="2" 
          d="M 50 200 L 25 10 L 175 10 L 150 200 L 100 200 Z" > 
    </path>
  </defs>
  <pattern id="жижа" width="100%" height="100%" >
    <line id="мера" x1="10" y1="200" x2="10" y2="200"> 
      <animate id="лей" attributeName="y2"
               from="200" to="10"
               begin="пуск.click" dur="1s"
               repeatCount="1" 
               fill="freeze"
               restart="whenNotActive" />
      <animate id="пей" attributeName="y2"
               from="10" to="200"
               begin="лей.end+.3s" dur="2s"
               repeatCount="1" 
               fill="freeze"
               restart="whenNotActive" />
    </line>
  </pattern>
  
  <use  xlink:href="#менза" />
  
  <g id="пуск"> 
    <rect x="5" y="160" rx="3" ry="3" 
          width="90" height="30"fill="#552" stroke="#2af" />
    <text x="15" y="180" fill="white" 
          font-size="16" font-weight="bold" font-family="Arial" >
          Наливай
    </text>
 </g> 
</svg>
```

Однако это была лишь разминка.
А не пора ли нам показать настоящий "тринкен-процесс", (?)

### **На троих:**

```css
#лить, #пить {cursor: pointer;}
#жижа {stroke:#f4a; stroke-width:200%; 
       stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-opacity:.8;
}
#тринк {box-shadow: #fff 0 0 8px 4px inset; background: 
  repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, #999, transparent .8%) fixed;
}
```

```html
<!-- SVG код -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg id="тринк" version = "1.1" baseProfile="full"
     width = "200px" height = "200px" 
     viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="none"> 
  <defs>
    <path id="штофф" fill="url(#жижа)" stroke="#0aa" stroke-width="2" 
          d="M 50,190 L 25,10 L 175,10 L 150,190 L 50,190 Z" /> 
    <linearGradient id="блик" x1="0" x2="100%">
         <stop offset="0%"  stop-color="#0aa"/>
         <stop offset="38%" stop-color="#eed"/>
         <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#0aa"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <pattern id="жижа" width="100%" height="100%">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%"  fill="url(#блик)" fill-opacity=".8"
          stroke="#0aa"  stroke-width="2"/>
    <line id="мера" x1="10" y1="200" x2="10" y2="200"/> 
  </pattern>
  
  <use  xlink:href="#штофф" />
  
    <g id="лить"> 
    <rect x="55" y="150" rx="3" ry="3" 
          width="90" height="30" fill="#da0" stroke="#288" stroke-width="2"/>
    <text font-size="16" font-weight="bold" font-family="Arial">
      <tspan id="" x="75" y="170" fill="#000">-Лей!-</tspan><!--  -->
    </text>
    </g> 
    <g id="пить" style="opacity:0;"> 
    <rect x="55" y="30" rx="3" ry="3" 
          width="90" height="30" fill="#0dd" stroke="#288" stroke-width="2"/>
    <text font-size="16" font-weight="bold" font-family="Arial"><!--  -->
      <tspan id="" x="75" y="50" fill="#000">-Пей!-</tspan>
    </text>
    </g> 
      <animate id="лей" xlink:href="#мера" attributeName="y2"
               from="200" to="10"
               begin="лить.click" dur="1s"
               repeatCount="1" 
               fill="freeze"
               restart="whenNotActive" />
      <animate id="лью" xlink:href="#лить" attributeName="opacity"
               from="1" to="0"
               begin="лить.click" dur="1s"
               repeatCount="1" 
               fill="freeze"
               restart="whenNotActive" />
      <animate id="лил" xlink:href="#пить" attributeName="opacity"
               from="0" to="1"
               begin="лей.end" dur="1s"
               repeatCount="1" 
               fill="freeze"
               restart="whenNotActive" />
  
      <animate id="пей" xlink:href="#мера" attributeName="y2"
               from="10" to="200"
               begin="пить.click" dur="2s"
               repeatCount="1" 
               fill="freeze"
               restart="whenNotActive" />
      <animate id="пью" xlink:href="#пить" attributeName="opacity"
               from="1" to="0"
               begin="пить.click" dur="1s"
               repeatCount="1" 
               fill="freeze"
               restart="whenNotActive" />
      <animate id="пил" xlink:href="#лить" attributeName="opacity"
               from="0" to="1"
               begin="пей.end" dur="1s"
               repeatCount="1" 
               fill="freeze"
               restart="whenNotActive" />
</svg>
<svg width="200px" height="200px" ><use  xlink:href="#штофф"/></svg>
<svg width="200px" height="200px" ><use  xlink:href="#штофф"/></svg>
```

Остальное - по мере поступления дополнительных комментариев...

Comment: Жижу заливаю ч-з паттерн...

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, Второй вариант более детально проработан...

Answer (score 5):

Не совсем уверен, не ушел ли я не в ту степь) Не svg, но довольно похоже. Работает с `-webkit-` в Chrome (в других не проверял). Изображение выступает в роли маски, применяется через `-webkit-mask-image`. Цвет меняется на каждом уровне в зависимости от общего прогресса.

```js
document.getElementById("range").addEventListener("input", e => {
  let val = e.target.value;
  let max = 1000;
  let lvlMax = 200;

  let currentlvlProgress = val % lvlMax / lvlMax * 100;
  let currentLvl = Math.ceil(val / lvlMax);
  let globalProgress = val / max * 100;
  let hue = currentLvl / (max / lvlMax) * 360;

  document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = `
    1 уровень: <b>${lvlMax}</b> очков<br>
    Всего уровней: <b>${max / lvlMax}</b><br>
    Текущий уровень: <b>${currentLvl}</b><br>
    Прогресс в уровне: <b>${currentlvlProgress}</b><br>
    Глобальный прогресс: <b>${globalProgress}</b><br>
    Изменение цвета: <b>${hue}</b> градусов<br>
  `;

  document.getElementById("progress").style.height = `${currentlvlProgress}%`;
  document.getElementById("progress").style.filter = `hue-rotate(${hue}deg)`;
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 14px;
}

body>* {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#icon {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  mask-size: 100% 100%;
  mask-position: 0 0;
  mask-image: url("https://cdn.vectorlogosupply.com/logos/large/2x/instagram-glyph-1-png-transparent-logo.png");
  -webkit-mask-size: 100% 100%;
  -webkit-mask-position: 0 0;
  -webkit-mask-image: url("https://cdn.vectorlogosupply.com/logos/large/2x/instagram-glyph-1-png-transparent-logo.png");
  -moz-mask-size: 100% 100%;
  -moz-mask-position: 0 0;
  -moz-mask-image: url("https://cdn.vectorlogosupply.com/logos/large/2x/instagram-glyph-1-png-transparent-logo.png");
}

#icon>#progress {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="icon">
  <div id="progress"></div>
</div>

<span id="info"></span>

<input type="range" max="1000" value="0" id="range">
```

Comment: Ушли немного) Не против если возьму ваш код, как основу под "механику" уровня?) **P.s.**, в мозиле не хочет работать)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 нет конечно, сам думал если с версткой пролечу, то хоть js пригодится))

Comment: Если по факту, то основная проблема в поддержке `mask`.
Сам код работает должным образом, только цвет должен, по задумке, меняется от уровня, 1 - один цвет, 2 - другой и т.д.)

Comment: Изменил расчет цвета. В FF 64.0.2 работает нормально. Сейчас еще добавил `-moz-`. Есть шанс, что и у вас заработает) Кст, константы уровней спецом другие взял, чтобы показать, что все адаптивное и можно настроить под себя.

Comment: Отлично, правда у меня всё равно не хочет работать) (FF DE 65.0b12)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, [здесь](https://codepen.io/warsan/pen/yRQGZd?editors=1100) тоже неплохой механизм есть. Я его вертикальным сделал, + клик мышки добавил...

Comment: @ВарламЕрофеич, залип на пару минут :D

Answer (score 1):

По сути идея была в создание "прогресс бара", который будет показывать прогресс до следующего уровня.

По условию вывод данных реализован, для задачи нам нужно **прогресс до нового уровня** - `$per` и **текущий уровень** - `$lvl`.

От `$lvl` будет зависеть цвет заполнения "прогресс бара", а так же это значение будет выводиться как визуальный счётчик.

`$per` же будет "двигать" ползунок нашего "прогресс бара".

```js
let colors = ['gray', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'violet', 'pink', 'darkred', 'gold'];
let pb = document.querySelector('#pb');

pb.setAttribute('height', document.querySelector('#per').value+'%');
pb.setAttribute('fill', colors[Number(document.querySelector('#lvl').value)]);

document.addEventListener('change', function(e){
  if(e.target.id === 'per') {
    pb.setAttribute('height', e.target.value+'%');
  }
  if(e.target.id === 'lvl') {
    pb.setAttribute('fill', colors[Number(e.target.value)]);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

#setting {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: scale(.75);
}
```

```html
<div id="setting">
<label for="per">Процент</label>
<input id="per" type="range" min="0" value="25" max="100">
<label for="lvl">Уровень</label>
<input id="lvl" type="number" min="0" value="0" max="9">
</div>

<svg width="100" viewbox="0 0 100 100" style="transform: rotate(180deg); box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red;">
  <!-- progress -->
  <rect id="pb" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="0"/>
</svg>
```

---

Основным моментом было реализация отличия фигур прогресса, каждые 100 уровней.

Для этого я решил упростить задачу и сделать несколько белых фигур на чёрном фоне (alpha) и использовать их в `mask` для `#pb` ("прогресс бар")

```js
let alpha = ['//i.imgur.com/RERMq4E.png', '//i.imgur.com/wHNvSCW.png', '//i.imgur.com/RAr3RmG.png'];
let colors = ['gray', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'violet', 'pink', 'darkred', 'gold'];
let pb = document.querySelector('#pb'),
    ma = document.querySelector('#ma');

pb.setAttribute('height', document.querySelector('#per').value+'%');
pb.setAttribute('fill', colors[Number(document.querySelector('#lvl').value)]);
ma.setAttribute('href', alpha[Number(document.querySelector('#alpha').value)]);

document.addEventListener('change', function(e){
  if(e.target.id === 'per') {
    pb.setAttribute('height', e.target.value+'%');
  }
  if(e.target.id === 'lvl') {
    pb.setAttribute('fill', colors[Number(e.target.value)]);
  }
  if(e.target.id === 'alpha') {
    ma.setAttribute('href', alpha[Number(e.target.value)]);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

#setting {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: scale(.75);
}
```

```html
<div id="setting">
<label for="per">Процент</label>
<input id="per" type="range" min="0" value="25" max="100">
<label for="lvl">Уровень</label>
<input id="lvl" type="number" min="0" value="0" max="9">
<label for="alpha">Alpha-mask</label>
<input id="alpha" type="number" min="0" value="0" max="2">
</div>

<svg width="100" viewbox="0 0 100 100" style="transform: rotate(180deg); box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red;">
  <!-- mask -->
  <mask id="mask">
    <image id="ma" width="100%" height="100%"></image>
  </mask>
  <!-- progress -->
  <rect id="pb" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="0" mask="url(#mask)"/>
</svg>
```

---

В целом уже всё готово, осталось фон, чтобы видно было какая фигура всё таки заполняется, для этого используем всё сразу, только без "прогресса".

```js
let alpha = ['//i.imgur.com/RERMq4E.png', '//i.imgur.com/wHNvSCW.png', '//i.imgur.com/RAr3RmG.png'];
let colors = ['gray', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'violet', 'pink', 'darkred', 'gold'];
let pb = document.querySelector('#pb'),
    ma = document.querySelector('#ma');

pb.setAttribute('height', document.querySelector('#per').value+'%');
pb.setAttribute('fill', colors[Number(document.querySelector('#lvl').value)]);
ma.setAttribute('href', alpha[Number(document.querySelector('#alpha').value)]);

document.addEventListener('change', function(e){
  if(e.target.id === 'per') {
    pb.setAttribute('height', e.target.value+'%');
  }
  if(e.target.id === 'lvl') {
    pb.setAttribute('fill', colors[Number(e.target.value)]);
  }
  if(e.target.id === 'alpha') {
    ma.setAttribute('href', alpha[Number(e.target.value)]);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

#setting {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: scale(.75);
}
```

```html
<div id="setting">
<label for="per">Процент</label>
<input id="per" type="range" min="0" value="25" max="100">
<label for="lvl">Уровень</label>
<input id="lvl" type="number" min="0" value="0" max="9">
<label for="alpha">Alpha-mask</label>
<input id="alpha" type="number" min="0" value="0" max="2">
</div>

<svg width="100" viewbox="0 0 100 100" style="transform: rotate(180deg);">
  <!-- mask -->
  <mask id="mask">
    <image id="ma" width="100%" height="100%"></image>
  </mask>
  <!-- background -->
  <rect id="bg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eee" mask="url(#mask)"/>
  <!-- progress -->
  <rect id="pb" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="0" mask="url(#mask)"/>
</svg>
```

---

И готово.

Единственный минус, пришлось перевернуть "с ног на голову", чтобы прогресс шёл снизу-вверх, если есть решения этого без `transform: rotate()` - готов выслушать.

Comment: 2 года и 2 месяца прошло. Не забыл вопрос :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, честно говоря, просто смотрел свои старые вопросы, наткнулся на этот, подумал и решил сделать так, как хотел)